# Why would a protocol droid act so nervous?

Tags: star-wars, droids

C-3PO has, in the words of [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-3PO) and [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84698/36103) related question, a "fussy and worry-prone personality". He reacts poorly to dangerous situations, usually exclaiming some variation of "we're all going to die!" For example, the very first line spoken in all of *Star Wars:*

> Did you hear that? They've shut down the main reactor. We'll be destroyed for sure.

In the top answer to the linked question, Null [claims that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/84744/36103) C-3PO's personality is (mostly) that of a standard protocol droid, and it is natural for one to become anxious in dangerous situations.

A [protocol droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Protocol_droid) often serves diplomatic functions. Negotiations and other diplomatic relations are potentially tense and stressful, and I think that you would want the people and droids involved to be able to stay calm.

While some of the situations in which we see Threepio—like actual battles—are probably outside normal operating parameters, he should still be able to deal with *some* level of stress. However, he even seems uncomfortable when working for Jabba the Hutt, even though that is exactly the sort of work protocol droids are *supposed* to do. Even in the more extreme situations, I can't think of any advantage to a diplomat or interpreter showing such visible fear and anxiety.

**What reason is there for a protocol droid, like C-3PO, to be so anxious in stressful situations?**

Comment: I think with just a tiny tweak, we can make this not a dupe.

Comment: @Richard I think that it *is* distinct from the other one (obviously, since I linked to it and asked this one anyway), but I'm having trouble explaining *why*.

Comment: The first question asks where C-3PO's personality comes from. The other question asks whether his personality is typical.

Comment: Both of the answers on the old question discuss the default nature of the personalities of protocol droids.

Comment: @phantom42 - I'm struggling. This question is similar but different. I've also got a pretty solid answer that *wouldn't* fit the other question.

Comment: @Richard Questions are different, but the answers there cover this at least enough for the dupe argument to be logical.

Comment: More than just protocol droids, why would **any** droid, of **any** type, with a default personality (droidonality?) be so fussy and worry-prone? Apart perhaps from Adamsesque monks, I can think of no type of droid that could possibly benefit from being constantly on the verge of a circuitous breakdown.

Comment: @Richard - either way, I have the out-of-universe answer.

Comment: @KSmarts - the short answer is that Lucas originally wrote C-3PO as a sleazy "oily car salesman" type who would say anything to get what he wanted.  Daniels read the lines on-set, but his dialogue was supposed to be overdubbed by a voice actor later.  He decided to speak his lines as a "snooty English butler" and the sound guy convinced Lucas to use Daniels' voice and interpretation of the character. Thus, a character who was supposed to be like a sleazy used car salesman became an uptight, "snooty English butler" instead.  Since butlers would be nervous on a battlefield, C-3PO is nervous.

Comment: @KSmarts - As far as working for Jabba, yes, 3PO was programmed to be a translator, but he had never worked for someone who tortured and dismembered translators who pissed him off.  C-3PO's first day on the job involved him going to a dungeon where he saw his predecessor being torn apart on a rack, and the first time we see him translating for Jabba, Jabba gets pissed at Leia-in-disguise and takes it out on 3PO.  3PO is used to translating, not being beaten up for no reason by a crimelord slug who enjoys seeing even his loyal guards being eaten by a Rancor.

Comment: @KSmarts - (cont'd) So 3PO's task in Jabba's palace was familiar and what he was programmed for, but the conditions, environment, company, and pressure were not. We can almost certainly assume that he had never previously been threatened with disintegration on the whim of his sadistic sociopathic boss, nor had anyone physically abused him for doing his job properly.  He was programmed to translate, not to be beaten when his master didn't like the things he was translating.  Jabba was probably the first person he'd met who was willing to "shoo the messenger" in a literal sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate here. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124897/if-c3po-is-a-protocol-droid-why-is-he-so-annoying